# Heroku Error installing Play

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0

I use Play v 2.2.3 and Java 1.7

I specified there in :

system.properties
dependencies.yml

in log :

```
-----> Play! app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7...done
-----> Installing Play! 2.2.3.....
-----> Error installing Play! framework or unsupported Play! framework version specified. Please review Dev Center for a list of supported versions.
! Push rejected, failed to compile Play! app
To git@heroku.com:whispering-brushlands-2197.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:whispering-brushlands-2197.git'
```

I am tired ... please i needed help

Comment: Do you have a Procfile? I could be mistaken, but I don't think dependencies.yml is used for Play 2.x on heroku

Comment: no.. 
where i should be put and what's the contents ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the [heroku-buildpack-play](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play) buildpack with a Play 2.x app. But it only supports Play 1.x. You can change to the [heroku-buildpack-scala](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala) buildpack by running:

`$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala`

Comment: Thank-you very match .. I think it's OK

this problem fixed